# Why can I not edit the location of my JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Code:

```
public class launcher implements ActionListener {

private static JFrame window;
private static JPanel panel; 

private JButton createPassword;
private JButton seePassword;

public launcher() {
    
    window = new JFrame(); 
    panel = new JPanel();
    
    window.setTitle("Password Vault");
    window.setSize(400, 260);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.getContentPane().add(panel); // Adds panel to JFrame
    
    createPassword = new JButton("Create Password");
    createPassword.setBounds(20, 100, 150, 100);
    createPassword.addActionListener(this);
    
    seePassword = new JButton("View Password");
    seePassword.setLocation(20, 50);
    seePassword.addActionListener(this);
    
    panel.add(createPassword);
    panel.add(seePassword);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new launcher();
}
```

Why can I not change the location of my JButtons? I have tried the setBounds and setLocation function but my buttons still stay on the top middle part of the JFrame window. I have also tried declaring my buttons inside the launcher() method and declaring them as a static variable.

Comment: The first thing you're going to want to do is look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), the next thing you'll want to do is pick a layout manager which will help you achieve the result you're after - pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI development

Comment: To add to the comment of @MadProgrammer & the answer of camickr: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). **General tips:** 1) `setVisible(true);` should be last, immediately after `pack()`  2) Swing (& AWT) GUIs should be created & updated on the EDT. ..

Comment: 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) A launcher might better appear in a `JDialog` or a `JWindow`. 5) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). I mention that because the code above would not compile cleanly due to missing methods. ..

Comment: .. In this case it is due to implementing an interface that is not required to display the layout problem, so remove the `implements ActionListener` and it should be set to compile, run and demonstrate the current layout.  6) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT attempt to set the size/location of your buttons.

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The layout manager will set the size/location of the button based on the rules of the layout manager.

The default layout manager for a JPanel is the `FlowLayout`, which is why you see the button centered.

If you want to position the buttons differently, then you need to change the layout manager.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

It looks like you want the buttons displayed vertically, so maybe a `BoxLayout` or `GridLayout` can be used depending on your exact requirement.

Other issues with your code:

1. Class names should start with an upper case character
2. There is no need to use static variables. That is not how the static keyword should be used
3. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.
4. You should be invoking pack() on the frame, BEFORE invoking setVisible(...) so the components can be displayed at their preferred size.

Comment: *"..pack() on the frame, instead of setVisible(...)"* I understand what you're getting at there, but the words might confuse a newbie.. How about instead *"..pack() on the frame, **before** setVisible(...)"* ?

Comment: I tried using the functions from BoxLayout but the button's position is still not moving.

Comment: @CrispyNuggets - Did you read the tutorial? Did you download the working examples from the tutorial and then make changes to display your buttons? Where is your [mre] showing how you used the BoxLayout? I can't guess why your code doesn't work yet the code in the tutorial does work.

Comment: I tried using BoxLayout but now my JButton is either on the top right, top middle, or top left of my screen even when I used Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT. I tried using the setAlignmentY function but the button still stays on the top of the screen.

Comment: I don't see an [mre] anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

While you really shouldn't change the place of your components without a layout manager, there is a way. If you put this line of code into your code, it should work with `setBounds`:

```py
window.setLayout(null);
```

Comment: Now the buttons don't appear on the window.

Comment: @CrispyNuggets, because Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Learn how to use Swing properly. You have been given plenty of advice, This may seem like a shortcut but it isn't and will learn to problems in the future.

Comment: @CrispyNuggets I agree with camickr, as this will lead to problems with being able to resize the window, and if yo are planning on making a professional app with swing, you should be able to resize the window. =D